# Android: How to download binary files from the internet

Tags: java, android, url, download

I want to download a file from the internet. And so far I have the ff. codes:

```
package com.example.downloadfile;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DownloadFile extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        String url = "http://www.fullissue.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Adam-Lambert.jpg";
        String FileName = "/LocalDisk/jm"; // save in your sdcard


        try{

            java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());
            java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(FileName);
            java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int x=0;
                while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
                    bout.write(data,0,x);               
                }
            fos.flush();
            bout.flush();
            fos.close();
            bout.close();
            in.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
            tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

      this.setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error, when I run this code, I got "**Error: /LocalDisk/jm**" in my UI.

Many thanks in advance for any help! I'm new to java and android dev... :)

Comment: When handling an exception, the `message` is not necessarily the most important part. At least equally important is the exception type and the stacktrace. Try `e.printStackTrace()` to get more details about the problem.

Comment: Also: `.close()` flushes the stream, there is no need to call `flush()` before. And closing `bout` will close `fos` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String FileName = "/LocalDisk/jm";

This is absolute path so you have to use it like this

```
String FileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jm"; // /sdcard/jm
```

More info about [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).
Also there is no good idea to download a file in UI thread cause it's blocking operation and may cause Activity Not Responding. The best way will be to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to handle this operation in background and notify the gui when you're done.

Comment: I'm not using an SD card, just the LocalDisk, is it possible? Thanks for the advice, I will study first the AsyncTask. :)

Comment: What is LocalDisk? There are basically two types of storage Internal and External. Internal is the internal storage and External is removable media like sd card.

Comment: Oh yeah, I mean Internal storage :D